# Getting "The data area passed to a system call is too small" in ASP.Net on server, but not on localhost

Tags: asp.net, iis

I've been scratching my head over this for half the day now. I am trying to secure the application to prevent any URL tampering, so when i stick a very long sting into the form action's URL parameter, it gets trapped and handled locally just find. But, when i upload it to the server, i get the following error "The data area passed to a system call is too small". Both machines are on IIS 6. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your IIS config is messed up, [here's a possible KB article.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/249721)

Try posting on [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/iis) also, this is more of a server config problem than a programming problem I think.

Comment: That KB article applies to IIS 4, but i did check that setting in IIS 6 and it was set properly. I'll try serverfault.com, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is it to do with the Query string being too long for the server to handle / process?

I recently ran into this with a GET request that passed a lot of query string parameters.

If I removed some of them the error went away, so I switched to `POST` instead.